# How can I read a .txt file letter by letter in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, file

How can I read a opened .txt-file in python letter by letter? I am a python beginner, and looked through the docs, but found nothing. 
P.S.: I'm using Python 2.7

Comment: What do you mean by `letter by letter`?

Comment: I mean that I load one letter, process it and load the following letter.